# How to shorten log4net logger path

Tags: c#, .net, log4net, .net-4.6

my log4net conversionpattern displays full path to class:

> ```
>     11:40:11,209 [C:\Users\martin\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\ViewModels\MainViewModel.cs] DEBUG - Test log
> ```

Is there a way how to shorten path to class name only?

> ```
>     11:40:11,209 [MainViewModel.cs] DEBUG - Test log
> ```

Answer (score 1):

It's also my typical experience to have trouble with the odd conversion nomenclature and the scant levels of documentation that seems to be available in a central location.

I have adapted the conversion pattern I normally use to get you something similar to what you requested:

```
<conversionPattern value="%d %-22.22c{1} %-5p - %m%n"/>
```

The `%-22.22c{1}` bit is the shortened class name (I guess) :)

The above will result in something like:

`2015-12-28 11:11:26,892 MyClass               DEBUG  - Test log`

Answer (score 0):

in the log4net configuration try using

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
 <conversionPattern value="%date [%-4thread] %-5level %logger{1} - %message%newline"/>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use conversion pattern value like following

```
<conversionPattern value="[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
```

See more in about [conversionPattern](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html)